# Meteor | Helper function. How to print attribute values of returned element on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I am using Meteor JS for UI development of a project. There is a helper method which takes a input parameter and return an object.

**Helper Function:**

```
"getPhoneName": function (param) {
        let myObj = PhoneRegister.findOne({"_id": param});
        //This myObj contains  name, _id, modelNumber
        return myObj;
    }
```

How i am using it on HTML

```
<span>{{getPhoneName 'id_1234'}}</span> //This line is obviously prints the [[Object]]

    Here i am not getting solution how to print modelNumber. I have tried following :
1.{{getPhoneName 'id_1234'.modelNumber}}
2.{{getPhoneName 'id_1234'}}.modelNumber
```

Can someone help? If you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mentioned you have this helper function:

```
getPhoneName (_id) {
  const myObj = PhoneRegister.findOne({_id});
  //This myObj contains  name, _id, modelNumber
  return myObj;
}
```

There are 2 ways to go based on your needs

---

First, if you want to get just the "name" as the helper implies `getPhoneName`, you can instead `return myObj.name;` (error handling to ensure myObj exists should also be considered).

You can then just use it:

```html
<p>The name of the phone is {{getPhoneName phoneId}}</p>
```

---

But, if you instead what to list a variety of information about the phone in your template, you can leave the helper alone and adjust your template in one of two different ways:

1) Use [`#let`](http://blazejs.org/api/spacebars.html#Let) to name your object within your template.

```html
{{#let currentPhone=(getPhoneName phoneId)}}
  <ul>
    <li>ID: {{currentPhone._id}}</li>
    <li>Name: {{currentPhone.name}}</li>
  </ul>
{{/let}}
```

2) Use [`#with`](http://blazejs.org/api/spacebars.html#With) to use that object as your data context without assigning a name

```html
{{#with getPhoneName phoneId}}
  <ul>
    <li>ID: {{_id}}</li>
    <li>Name: {{name}}</li>
  </ul>
{{/let}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want one property, you could simply `return myObj.property;` and display it as you already did with `{{getPhoneName 'id_1234'}}`.
But if you want to access multiple properties, you can return the object in an array and then use [each](http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Each-and-With) or [each-in](http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Each-in) Blaze's built-in block like this :

**Helper:**

```
"getPhoneName": function (param) {
        let myObj = PhoneRegister.findOne({"_id": param});
        //This myObj contains  name, _id, modelNumber
        return [myObj];  // Returning an array in order to use each or each-in
    }
```

**HTML (with each):**

```
{{#each getPhoneName 'id_1234'}}
    <span>{{this.property1}}</span>
    <span>{{this.property2}}</span>
{{/each}
```

You can also take a look at [{{#let}}](http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Let), in some cases it's useful too.